# Iterated antiderivatives of polynomials having many real roots

Tags: polynomials, ds.dynamical-systems

> **Question** For which polynomials $p_n:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ having $n$ distinct real roots can we find an infinite sequence of polynomials
> $$ p_n, p_{n+1}, p_{n+2} , p_{n+3}, \dots, $$
> such that  $p_i$ is a polynomial of degree $i$ with $i$ distinct real roots and $p_{i+1}$ is an anti-derivative of $p_i$ for all $i \geq n$?

Hermite polynomials have this property. The $n-$th Hermite polynomial $H_n$ has $n$ distinct roots and satisfies the derivative relation
$$ \frac{d}{dx} H_n = n H_{n-1}.$$
This means that when computing the antiderivative of $H_{n}$, one can always find the correct constant to turn the anti-derivative into a multiple of $H_{n+1}$ and multiples of $H_{n+1}$ have exactly $n+1$ roots.  My gut feeling would be that this is a very special property that not many polynomials have and I am wondering whether there is any sort of result in that direction.

**Motivation** This question is motivated by the asymptotic behavior of roots of polynomials when polynomials are differentiated many times. A while back I proposed a PDE to describe this and the PDE seems to be smoothing, so there should be a loss of information as one differentiates. More recently, Jeremy Hoskins and I proved a [result](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.09809.pdf) that also hints towards loss of information. This sort of suggests that having these infinite chains should be somehow `rare' in some sense but it's more a vague connection than anything theorem-based.

Comment: The discriminant of $p$ is polynomial in the coefficients of $p$ and vanishes just when $p$ has multiple roots. So given $p$, the discriminant of $p + C$ is a polynomial in $C$, and so only finitely many choices of $C$ will have $p + C$ have multiple roots. So you should always be able to do this.

Comment: I don't think it's always possible. If we take (-1 + x) (-0.8 + x) (0.8 + x) (1 + x), then no matter what constant we choose for the antiderivative, the antiderivative cannot have more than 3 real roots. The problem is not only about the roots being distinct, they should also all be real.

Comment: Oops, missed the 'real', you're right!

Comment: The question is equivalent to asking for which power series
$F(x)\in\mathbb{C}[[x]]$ is it true that if $e^{tx}F(x)=\sum_{n\geq
0}P_n(t)\frac{x^n}{n!}$, then all the roots (or zeros) of $P_n(t)$ are
real. This seems to be quite a rare property. Possible
examples other than $e^{-x^2}$ and some related ones like
$(1+x)e^{-x^2}$ are $\cosh\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{x}\sinh\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: Even more generally, power series like $F(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{n!(2n+1)!(5n+3)!}$ also seem to work (if Maple can be trusted).

Comment: The question seems to be answered at the "Untitled" link from https://canvas.wisc.edu when you do a google search on "appell sequence real zeros". I don't see how $F(x)=\sum \frac{x^n}{n!^2}$ fits into the picture. If this doesn't actually work, what is the least $n$ for which $P_n(t)$ has a nonreal zero?

Comment: Ah, this is fantastic, this leads to a complete characterization!   This is tremendously helpful -- thank you!   I would award the bounty if it was an answer, I am not sure I can award it to a comment.

Comment: @StefanSteinerberger, for the thrill of receiving my first bounty, I will convert my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question seems to be answered at the "Untitled" link from canvas.wisc.edu when you do a google search on "appell sequence real zeros".

Comment: Here is the link Richard is referring to: https://canvas.wisc.edu/files/17888266/download?download_frd=1

Comment: It seems likely that these are notes of Benedek Valkó (http://www.math.wisc.edu/~valko/courses/833/833.html) but I'm not 100% sure...